# Iconize behaves in a confusing manner

Tags: functions, core-language

When I evaluate `Iconize[Range[10], "range10"]`, it returns an icon labled "range10", which if evaluated returns `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10}`. If I change the original input cell to `Iconize[Range[5], "range10"]` and evaluate it again, it returns a new icon labled "range10", which evaluates to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. If I now evaluate the pushed down original "range10" icon, it evaluates to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10}`. This is a bit confusing to me.  What's happening?

Comment: `"range10"` is just a label that you set, so it is irrelevant. The object you created live in the notebook (not the kernel). This means that there are precisely as many objects as you see on the screen. You see two—so there are two. They are distinct. Maybe the most intuitive understanding is to think of the contents of these iconized objects as being tied to their displayed location.

Comment: After I read Mass Defect's answer, I selected an icon and pressed ctrl-shift-e. The icon was instantly replaced by the iconized data. As he said, the icon is "exactly identical to the original data."  Pretty neat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of whatever has been iconized as being exactly identical to the original data (it is!). The icon is essentially just a representation that fits nicely into the front end without taking up your entire screen. For all intents and purposes, it **is** the original data. I often use it if I have a large data set (a few thousand rows) that I want to store inside of the notebook rather than re-importing it every time.

If you click the little plus button on both, you should see that the two icons contain different amounts of data.

When using `Iconize`, Mathematica does not assign the data to a variable, therefore it cannot be overwritten by calling `Iconize` again, even if the two icons are given the same label. What happens is Mathematica cuts the data out of your Notebook, transforms it into an icon, and then pastes that icon back into your Notebook. Therefore, it is possible to assign an icon to a variable.

Notice the differences in the way I use them below. `r2 + 5` returns the icon plus 5, but the icon itself (r3) plus 5 returns the list with 5 added to each element (the same as `r1 + 5`).

A useful way to use icons is to type:

```
r4 = Iconize[Range[15], "My Label Here"]
```

Then select everything **after** the equals sign, choose "Evaluate in Place" from the Evaluation menu, and then evaluate the entire cell the way you normally would. `r4` is now exactly the data that you iconized and can be used in the same way that your data would be. Notice that this is different from if you were to type the above and then simply evaluate the cell.

[image: Results of Iconize.]

Comment: Nicely explained. It's really useful functionality, but the documentation is a little sparse!

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks! I agree, I love it for datasets that I always need in a notebook but don't want to have to re-import them every time I open the notebook. Especially if I'm sending it to someone else, it's nice to not have to also send the data file.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the label (the second argument to `Iconize`) has nothing to do with the contents at all, and isn't a unique identifier.

Thus labelling two `Iconize` outputs the same thing doesn't have any effect upon their contents - it's **purely cosmetic**.

[image]

Comment: I see that. The unique identifier appears to be the icon itself, sort of. That created a problem for me that I need to think about a bit to express clearly.  I might have just thought of a solution, which I need to try.